# What is the meaning of the colors near methods in the API documentation?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, joomla-framework-1.x

when i look into api.joomla.org to view available functions i always see a Little GREEN Vertical Bar to all functions where they are explained, but some functions have orange bar what they mean by  orange and green bars ? for batter understand i also included a snapshot below

1. i also read JModelList class file and i found a function
   getListQuery() but this function is not shown at Joomla JModelList
   api page, is this function going to be deprecated.?
2. secondly how do i view only function that are not inherited from
   base class!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Green marked functions are public ones. Orange are protected. Private methods are red.

1) Look at the filter buttons in the left hand side. Maybe some functions do not appear according to how these are set.

2) You have, as I said, filters above the left-handed list of functions. These you can use to filter out inherited methods (by clicking *down* the "Inherited"-Button).

Comment: i removed all filters, but it did not show getListQuery() function, and yes i had also clicked upon inherited filter button but it did not show me getListQuery() which is not a inherited function, and if orange is for public and green for protected then why it show green and orange when i clicks upon private it should not show orange because public function can not be private.? can you please clear it more

Comment: @SumerRajChouhan - He said public is green and protected or orange. Not the other way round ;) Have a look at Joomla's Database Driver API which shows everything: https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseDriver.html

Comment: still not found a clear answer

Comment: @SumerRajChouhan: I'm sorry, but I'm able to see getListQuery() on the page you mention (https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JModelList.html). It is a protected method, and appears in the API three positions under the createTable() method.